# How to create a given highchart in angular

Tags: highcharts, angular12

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHVmG.png)

I want to create a chart like image, As I see the chart it looks like a line chart but at the bottom also has some green yellow and red coloured portions. How to implement such type of chart using highcharts in angular 12?

```
I have created a line chart but I want bottom portion also which is there in the attached image.

chartOptions = {
          chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
          },
         
          title: {
            text: 'test',
            align: 'left'
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          xAxis: {
            showEmpty: true,
            ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
            crosshair: {
              width: 3,
              snap: true,
              color: 'gray'
            },
          },
          yAxis: {
            showEmpty: true,
            ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
            title: {
              text: null,
            },
              },
          tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            followPointer: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: '12px',
            },
          },
          series: [
            {
              data: [1, 2, 3, 4,  2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6,7,1, 9,2,1, 3,4, 5,2, 1, 7, 9, 2, 1, 3, 3,4, 1,3,4,6,1,2,4,5,6,3,2,5,2,6,7,8,8,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,6,8,9,2,1,2,4,6,3,6,7,8,1,4,6,7,8,3,5,5,6,2,1,2,1,1,1,1],
              name: 'line chart',
              type: 'line',
              fillOpacity: 0.3,
            },
          ],
        };
```

Comment: I'm not clearly sure what are you looking for.  Mixing `line` series with the `xrange` looks quite similar https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qdsm61t0/, however, It seems you want to show colors dynamically. Check the following proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lczw90kn/

Comment: @magdalena Yes I want to create a composite charts. I want to show  colors dynamically adding according to the line points. I have referred your solution  jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lczw90kn but in this  where is the addSeries method implemented. Also from where 'this.series[0].data' is getting added?

Comment: I use 'this.series[0].data' and addSeries() to calculate the color because this particular chart is not available by default in Highcharts. However, if you intend to use dynamic data, I'm afraid that the solution will not be suitable for you due to the technical limitations of 'zones'. It appears to be more of a custom implementation, and you can submit it as a feature request on our Github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose